# HTML parent element height is Zero, but child height isn't

Tags: html, css

The problem is i will stack html elements over each other but, in the div where i do this is the height always zero. And the html elements behind them are under them.

```css
.parent {
    position: relative;
}
.child {
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div class="child">1</div>
    <div class="child">2</div>
 </div>
 <p>under the other</p>
```

And now the height of the parent object should adapt to the children.

Comment: what exactly do you want? Is is not so clear. Please be specific and as clear as you can be.

Comment: If you use position absolute it takes the element out of the flow. It's like it doesn't exist for the parent element. That's why it has a height of 0, there is no content inside it. What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: You declared `position: absolute` on the child element. That moves the element out of the flow. As such the parent has no content anymore (flow-wise) and will be calculated and rendered with 0 height.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"And now the height of the parent object should adapt to the children."*

That's what you'd expect from tags in normal flow, but the parent and children are [`position: relative` and `absolute` so behavior is totally different](https://css-tricks.com/absolute-relative-fixed-positioining-how-do-they-differ/)
In the example is the OP code with outlines and another copy of OP but they have `position: static`, which is default.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  outline: green 5px dotted;
}

.child {
  height: auto;
  width: auto;
  position: absolute;
}

.child:first-of-type {
  outline: dashed 3px red;
  color: red;
}

.child:last-of-type {
  outline: dashed 3px blue;
  color: blue;
}

.x {
  position: static
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
</div>
<p>under the other</p>

<hr>

<div class="parent x">
  <div class="child x">1</div>
  <div class="child x">2</div>
</div>
<p>under the other</p>
```